# How can I fix this bug with ScyllaDB?

Tags: scylla

I'm trying to work through the ScyllaDB tutorial series here: https://www.scylladb.com/2017/11/30/mutant-monitoring-system-day-1/

I've got a Docker container running (on Windows, using Powershell) and have cloned their repo, and run it with Docker Compose:

```
PS C:\repos\scylla-code-samples\mms> docker-compose up -d
mms_scylla-node3_1 is up-to-date
mms_scylla-node2_1 is up-to-date
Creating mms_scylla-node1_1 ... done
```

Trying to check its status with the nodetool returns a container restarting error:

```
PS C:\repos\scylla-code-samples\mms> docker exec -it mms_scylla-node1_1 nodetool status
>>
Error response from daemon: Container c2940e14078fcdbbcf70f60392b05eb3d5c90273a15970c8575aad46cd797a02 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

The logs show these unexpected end of file errors:

```
2019-03-05T09:39:36.882128500Z /start.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
2019-03-05T09:40:38.038237500Z /start.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
2019-03-05T09:40:38.038383700Z /start.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
2019-03-05T09:41:38.922861400Z /start.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
2019-03-05T09:41:38.923067400Z /start.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
2019-03-05T09:42:39.801821900Z /start.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
2019-03-05T09:42:39.802078500Z /start.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
2019-03-05T09:43:40.696641100Z /start.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
2019-03-05T09:43:40.696928800Z /start.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How can I fix this, preferably without writing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, you can try using the Docker Toolbox which uses a Virtual Box based docker host rather than the one that's part of the new "Docker for Windows". This ensure that you are running on Linux without having a Linux box.

Even though it says "Legacy Desktop Solution" It still works well.

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Answer (score 2):

The `\r`  is indicative of windows-style carriage returns, so maybe it is related to your Windows environment somehow. Advise is to try this on a Linux box, and in parallel open a bug with the scylla-code-samples.git project so that it can be fixed.

Comment: The root cause is MMS examples are building a Scylla Docker image with some tweaks instead of using the standard Scylla Docker from Docker Hub. I open a Github issue to fix it https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-code-samples/issues/79